# Logic and spaces in Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex:

```
^(?P<port>[\w\-\>]+)(?P<virtual_route> +None|None)\s+(?P<port_state>\w)\s+(?P<link_state>[\w]+)\s+(?P<auto_neg>[\w]+)\s+(?P<cfg_speed>[\d]+) (?P<actual_speed>[\d\s]+)(?P<cfg_duplex>[\w]+)
```

That I use on the following configuration:

```
MLAG-ISC>None       E       A   OFF 40000 40000 FULL FULL   NONE     1  Q+CR4_1m
2        None       E      NP   OFF 10000       FULL                    NONE
3        None       E      NP   OFF 10000       FULL                    NONE
4        None       E      NP   OFF 10000       FULL                    NONE
MLAG-ISC>None       E       A   OFF 40000 40000 FULL FULL   NONE     1  Q+CR4_1m
6        None       E      NP   OFF 10000       FULL                    NONE
```

Which gives me this result (https://regex101.com):

[image]

This is the result I want however I would also like to capture the next FULL or empty, NONE or empty, 1 or empty and Q+CR4_1m or NONE. I just can't seem to make it work because of the spaces in the rows 2,3,4 and 6.

Note that I am using Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `FULL`, `NONE` and `1` are the only possible (though optional) values in that columns:

```
^(?P<port>[\w\-\>]+)(?P<virtual_route> +None|None)\s+(?P<port_state>\w)\s+(?P<link_state>[\w]+)\s+(?P<auto_neg>[\w]+)\s+(?P<cfg_speed>[\d]+) (?P<actual_speed>\d*)\s+(?P<cfg_duplex>[\w]+)\s+((?:FULL)?)\s+((?:NONE)?)\s+(1?)\s+([\w+]+)
```

otherwise:

```
^(?P<port>[\w\-\>]+)(?P<virtual_route> +None|None)\s+(?P<port_state>\w)\s+(?P<link_state>[\w]+)\s+(?P<auto_neg>[\w]+)\s+(?P<cfg_speed>[\d]+) (?P<actual_speed>\d*)\s+(?P<cfg_duplex>[\w]+)[^\S\r\n]+(\w*)[^\S\r\n]+(\w*)[^\S\r\n]+(\d*)[^\S\r\n]+([\w+]+)
```

Comment: You're a legend, the last one is perfect, but I would like to capure them as actual_duplex, flow_cntrl, load_master and media. Sorry I'm just starting to figure out how these Regual Expressions work... :)

Comment: Add `?P<actual_duplex>` ecc. after each open parenthesis, exactly like for the other capturing groups. See also https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html